# format string with multiple values in terraform

Tags: terraform, string-formatting, terraform0.12+

Terraform version = .12+

I'm wondering if there's a way to format a single string with multiple values.

I've tried using the terraform [format function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/format.html) like so:

```
bucket = format("%-%", 'dev', "test")
bucket = format("%-%", ['dev', "test"])
```

which both output the error:

```
Call to function "format" failed: unrecognized format character '%' at offset
2.
```

The expected formatted value would be `dev-test`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code should be:

```
bucket = format("%s-%s", "dev", "test")
```

It uses `%s` as well as double quotes for `dev`.

The formatting marks available are detailed [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/format.html#specification-syntax).